# Take picture in Background like AirDroid

Tags: android, service, android-camera

I know you think there is so many question like this but I want to tell that ,in every topics every one said its not possible to take picture without showing surface in some devices like HTC One X and ... .I install Airdrop app in all of this device and use the camera in Airdrop and its work fine !! and there is no such a surface View in the device screen !!
so how can we explain this ?

( sorry for my basic english)

[AirDroid in PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

Answer (score 1):

> in every topics every one said its not possible to take picture without showing surface in some devices like HTC One X and ... .I install Airdrop app in all of this device and use the camera in Airdrop and its work fine !!

This maybe because AirDroid would still be showing the `SurfaceView` but it's height and weight must be set to `1px` thus making it too minuscule to be noticed.

Comment: i checked the Airdroid when its working . when i began to use camera in airdroid a Service started and named CameraPreviewSerice .